# Are these the proper regex expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a few regex strings to use in my syntax highlighter, this if the first time I have ever used them and I am having a deal of difficulty...

The first four are, I will have a specified character followed by any number of numbers, match it.

- The best I have is `"G[0-9]|G[0-9][0-9]|G[0-9][0-9][0-9]"` to match either `G#`, `G##`, or `G###`

but I want to do G with any number of numbers after it.

The next three are, I will have a character (X,Y,Z, or P) and I want to match it if there is no letter or symbol behind it

- `"[X|Y|Z|P][0-9]"`

These next few are harder, match `"#11.11=11.11"` where 1 is a number and there can be any number of numbers between the pound sign, the periods, and the equal sign. And the periods do not have to be there can also be `"#11=11"` or `" #1.1=11"` or `"#11=1.1"`

- I have no idea... `"#[0-9][ |.]   ..."`

Anything after a `" ' "` and between a newline

- `'[A-Za-z0-9]\n"`  but I know this only gives me one character...

And the easy one I think is anything between two `()` or `[]`

- `"(*) | [*]"`?

Comment: You can test your regular expressions with a tool like http://regexpal.com/

Comment: `G[0-9]{1,3}` for the first. `(X|Y|Z|P)[0-9]` for the second (your version is buggy).

Comment: I like expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) myself.

Comment: MSDN is your friend.  This should help you figure out at least some of your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx/#Quantifiers

Comment: also visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for good reading on how to wirte regexes

Comment: A good little-known regex tester: http://refiddle.com Supports multiple flavors.

Comment: Oh my, a question regarding regular expressions and this many people answer in such a short amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but tested using regexpal

1) G[0-9]{1-3} - the '{1-3}' specifies the last symbol to occur one to three times.

2) ((.*|)) - you put a '\' before the '(' and ')' as escape characters

3) [0-9]1*(.|)1*=1*(.|)1 - this matches your three examples

4) \'.*\n - I think this should work... '\n' represents a new line char right?

5) ((|[).*()|]) - this one has those escape characters again

Again...quick and dirty. Regexpal.com is your friend

Comment: Number 5 is problematic - your regex will validate `"[qwe)"` (opening and closing bracket are of different types), which I'm not sure it's suppose dto.

Comment: Hmm... These answers are all very nice and work. But, the bigger question is how do I tell MVS that \d is not supposed to be an escape character? It thinks my strings (regexs) have unrecognized escape characters

Comment: Either use verbatim strings (`@"\d"`) or double-escape the backslash (`"\\d"`).

Comment: This would be useful, but for the first one, the OP wants to match any number of numbers, not just between one and three numbers.

Comment: in that case it would be '[0-9]*' I guess I was just matching his examples.

Comment: @spots `[0-9]+` or `\d+` would be more accurate if the OP wants one or more which I think the OP does.

Comment: What about this one. From the character P but no including P, everything until a newline character, match. I think it is ""P.*\\n" But this still matches the P which I just want the characters after the P to match.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "negative look-ahead."
"(!?P).*" will match any character that starts with a P, but won't include P in the match. I'll leave the rest up to you! 

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

1> G[0-9]{1,3}

2> No, it's WRONG.
The correct one is [XYZ][0-9]
(you do not use an OR operator (|), but just write the characters side by side within square braces)

Comment: The way they used is not "wrong", but rather, not as concise.  Both methods will get the same result.

Comment: What if I want to match just the X, but only if a letter is following it.

Answer (score 1):

For G with any number of digits after it

```
\b([Gg]\d+)\b
```

This matches a wordboundary (\b) followed by a lower or upper G [Gg], followed by 1 or more (+) digits (\d), followed by a wordboundary (\b)

> The next three are, I will have a character (X,Y,Z, or P) and I want
>   to match it if there is no letter or symbol behind it

This is a little tougher

```
\b[XYZP]([\W]|_)
```

This matches an XYZ or P followed by a non-word character \W, (word characters are typically a-z, 0-9 and the underscore), so after saying we don't want a word character, we add in that the _ is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

> And the easy one I think is anything between two () or []
>
> ```
> "(*) | [*]"?
> ```

`@"\([^(]*\)"` and `@"\[[^\[]*\]"`

It means: an open bracket - then any number of characters which are not an open bracket - and a close bracket.

Slashes are required to indicate to the regex engine that brackets should be treated literally.

`@` - verbatim string - is to inform C#, in turn, that those slashes should be taken literally and not as C# escape characters.

> Anything after a `" ' "` and between a newline

Similarly: `@"'[^']*\n"`

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you can use this Regex :

```
^G\d+
```

Comment: assuming he wants it to start with a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look up how to use regexes. Having said that:

> I will have a specified character followed by any number of numbers, match it

```
G\d+
```

> I will have a character (X,Y,Z, or P) and I want to match it if there
>   is no letter or symbol behind it

```
(?<!\w)[XYZP][0-9]
```

> These next few are harder, make "#11.11=11.11" blue

Huh?

> Anything after a " ' " and between a newline

```
'(.+?)\n
```

> And the easy one I think is anything between two () or []

```
\(.+?\)|\[.+?\]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `G\d+`
2. `[XYZP](?=\d)`
3. `#(\d+(\.\d+)?)=(\d+(\.\d+)?)`
4. `'.*?\n`
5. `\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]`

[Regex explanation here.](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

Answer (score 1):

The first one:

```
G[0-9]+
```

In regular expressions `+` means at least 1 or more (repetitions of the previous "characters").
You could also use `*` for none or any number of repetitions.

The second might be something like this:

```
^(X|Y|Z|P)$
```

This actually matches only if it's at the beginning of a line and has *no* characters behind. If you want it to be anywhere and only exclude certain characters behind it, modify the following:

```
[XYZP][^0-9a-z]
```

This is X or Y or Z or P followed by NOT 0-9 and NOT a-z

Notice that I use the OR character `|` in the first example in brackets, but not in the square brackets.

For the third one:

```
#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Might not be 100 percent correct, I always confuse when to escape which characters. You might need to escape `#` and `=`.

For the last one:

```
(\(.*\)|\[.*\])
```

Answer (score 1):

I use perl for regex, but it should hopefully be the same as what you're looking for.

For the first one, `G[0-9]+` should work. The square brackets means that the regex looks for only one of the characters within the brackets (the characters being 0 through 9) and the `+` right after it means that it looks for one or more matches.

The second is a bit more tricky, but I would use `\s[XYPZ]`. The square brackets function the same as before, only matching one of X, Y, P or Z. Also the `\s` matches any whitespace character (tab, space, newline, etc.).

For the third one, I would try `#[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+=[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+`. If we go from left to right, we encounter `\.?` and it's new. `\.` matches a literal period (you have to escape it with the backslash, as just a period by itself means that it can match one of any character). The question mark means that the period can either be there or not (matches zero or one instance of a period).

The fourth one: `'.*\n`. The combination of the period by itself and the asterisk means that it'll match zero or more characters, the characters being anything at all. I'm not too sure if you need to escape the single quotes though.

And for the fifth one, `(\(.*\)|\[.*\])` should do the trick. You need to escape the `[]()` inside the brackets because they mean something by themselves. Also, the `|` means or, so the regex can either matches whatever is on the left side of the bar, or on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify repetitions in different ways. A star "*" after a term means, repeat the term zero, one or several times. A plus sign "+" means, repeat the term one or several times. You can also specify a number range with `{n,m}`. In your case the expression would be

```
G\d{1-3}
```

where `\d` is a digit.

---

With this expression you can match a position that does not preceed a suffix

```
find(?!suffix)
```

I am not sure what you mean by symbol

```
[XYZP](?![a-zA-Z specify your symbols here])
```

---

For the pound number

```
\#\d+(\.\d+)?=\d+(\.\d+)?
```

`\#`        the pound sign
`\d+`       at least one digit
`(\.\d+)?`  optionally (`?`) a period succeeded by at least one digit
            finally an equal sign succeeded by another number

---

Everything between "'" and \n. Use this pattern here, which finds a position between a prefix and a suffix.

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)

(?<=').*(?=\n)
```

`.*` means any character as many times as possible. Alternatively you could use

```
(?<=').*?(?=\n)
```

`.*` means any character as few times as possible, if too many `\n` are taken. Also be carefult with the RegexOption.Multiline. Depending on its setting you will have to test for the end of line with `$` instead of `\n`.

---

For the parentheses () or [] you can use the same pattern again

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)

(?<=\().*?(?=\))|(?<=\[).*?(?=])
```

where `|` is the alternative.